# aws amplify auth.js not working with android emulator

Tags: android, react-native, authentication, amazon-cognito

I have created a basic POC app react native app. Lambda behind an API gateway guarded by cognito.

I was prototyping my expo app code with the web interface, and everything works as expected there. I get the aws provided login screen, I can sign up, click forget password ect.

I have tried my code with an android studio provided android emulated device, and on this emulated device none of the buttons on the aws provided login screen work. I can enter into the login fields username and password, but when I click on the button nothing happens, and I have seen no request flying away in the network tab.

Anyone have a take on this? Please let me know what can I provide to help you help me..